# Building agents with integrated GUI in jade

Tags: java, agent, agents-jade, multi-agent

I want to create a Multi Agent application integrated with UI. Up to now i have create some agent applications, but the problem was i don't know how to integrate UI.

It could be a great help if anyone could provide me tutorial or example to start on.]
Thanks.

Comment: have you tried google it? https://www.google.com/search?q=gui+jade why the available solutions are not enough for you?

Comment: Thanks darlinton , i will try those links.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have just created instances of windows.

```
windowInstace= new guiWindow();)
```

then use the variables in a cyclic-behaviour e.g.:

```
if (windowInstace.start()==true) 
{
     startMethod();
 }
```

If you're going to do this check out the takedown method for cleanup.
It also helps by closing the GUI if the agent dies.

```
protected void takeDown()
{
        System.out.println(""+window);

    if(window!=null)
    {
            window.dispose();

    }
            removeBehaviour(checkForParts);


}
```